# How to get loggedin customer information in laravel Multiple Authentication with database session driver?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I've two types of user admin (default users table) and customer (I created customers table). I've used a session with a database driver shipped with laravel-jetstream. I've no issue with the admin authentication. I'm getting user information successfully for admin. But when I log in with the customer, I do get logged in but not getting any logged-in customer information. I've checked the database.

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
    ],
],
```

customer login

```
public function login(Request $request) : object
{
    if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }else {
        return back()->withErrors(['message' => 'Incorrect email or password']);
    }
}
```

My session table looks like below

```
Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->primary();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
        $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
        $table->text('payload');
        $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
    });
```

I understand **$table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->index();** pointed to default user id.
In case of customer, How do I store customer Id and retrieve information properly?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I did a silly mistake.

```
{{ Auth::guard('customer')->user()->name }}
```

I missed the guard.